# how to use navigation api in grails 3.3.8

Tags: grails

According to this doc: http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html

You should be able to put the following in your main layout:

```
<nav:primary/>
<nav:secondary/>
```

and it should magically add all your controllers according to the docs:

> To get you started quickly, all your controllers will be
>   automatically registered in the "app" scope and each controller has
>   sub-items for each of it actions.

How to reproduce:

1. created an app with grails create-app
2. added a domain object with grails create-domain-class Address
3. added a few string fields to the Address class.
4. created a scaffolded controller thus:

   class AddressController {
       static scaffold = Address
   }
5. edited the /views/layouts/main.gsp thusly:

```html
</head>
<body>

<nav:primary/>
<nav:secondary/>
<!---
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#">
      <asset:image src="grails.svg" alt="Grails Logo"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0.8px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <g:pageProperty name="page.nav" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ---!>

    <g:layoutBody/>

    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
```

1. Ran the app.  The result was just a blank navigation, and the nav tags were unaltered in the resultant page in the browser.

I also tried doing "grails generate-all Address" to create the static view and controller, and I added the following line in the controller:

```
   static navigationScope = 'app'
```

But this had no effect either.

Comment: That taglib is part of a Grails 2 plugin called `platform-core` - the plugin was not ported to Grails 3.

Comment: @erichelgeson that explains it, although I did see a plugin in grails 3 called core which I assumed was it.  What do grails 3 users do for nav?  Hard code in layouts?

Comment: You could either look at the code in the `platform-core` taglib and adapt it to your app or write your own.